# Generate signed S3 url using boto3 with specified storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I can successfully upload a file to S3 using both `generate_presigned_url()` and `generate_presigned_post()` without specifying a storage class.

As soon as I try to specify a storage class I receive an error.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

s3_client = boto3.client(service_name='s3',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
s3_client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='put_object',Params={'Bucket':bucket,'Key':'test.txt', 'StorageClass':'INTELLIGENT_TIERING'})
```

fails with

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your key and signing method.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

s3_client = boto3.client(service_name='s3',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
parts=s3_client.generate_presigned_post(Bucket=bucket,Key='test.txt', Fields={'StorageClass':'INTELLIGENT_TIERING'})
files = {'file':open('test.txt')}
response=requests.post(parts['url'], data=parts['fields'], files=files)
```

fails with

> Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields: StorageClass

I've tried the latter approach with "Storage-Class", "x-amz-storage-class", and a variety of different key names with the same result.

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE: more info**

I don't believe I have any permission issues since this works:

```
s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket,Key='test.txt', StorageClass='INTELLIGENT_TIERING', Body=binary_data)
```

Also, I get the same signature mismatch error noted above with `generate_presigned_url()` if I replace `INTELLIGENT_TIERING` with `STANDARD`. Seems to not be an issue of the new class being unsupported.

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#example-storage-class-condition-key, x-amz-storage-class only supports STANDARD, STANDARD_IA, and REDUCED_REDUNDANCY. It does not indicate the new Intelligent Tiering class. Maybe that's because the documentation simply hasn't caught up, or maybe the underlying validation of x-amz-storage-class genuinely does not yet support Intelligent Tiering. Try with STANDARD_IA and if that works then the signature calculation error is because you have supplied an invalid (or "not yet supported") storage class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per this comment](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1824#issuecomment-451228547)

> By adding the 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD_IA' into the params you're
>   including it as part of the signature as a signed header, this is just
>   how S3 serializes the storage class. All headers that are signed need
>   to be sent with the request when you used the presigned url. In this
>   case you would need to include the following header in your PUT
>   request:
>
> headers = {'x-amz-storage-class': 'STANDARD_IA'}

I hadn't been including the header 'x-amz-storage-class' in my client when calling the url generated via generate_presigned_url because I'd assumed the url contained all the info S3 needed. Adding it resolved this.

Answer (score -1):

More than likely the ability to define your storage class is being blocked by your AWS IAM permissions:

> By default s3:PutObject stores objects using the STANDARD storage class, but you can use the x-amz-storage-class request header to specify a different storage class.
>
> When granting the s3:PutObject permission, you can use the s3:x-amz-storage-class condition key to restrict which storage class to use when storing uploaded objects. For more information about storage classes, see Storage Classes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#example-storage-class-condition-key

Are you in a position to share the IAM permissions that is set for your S3 bucket upload?

Assuming you have access to the IAM permissions, you may find that a restriction was added as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-storage-class": [
                        "STANDARD"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: A runtime IAM policy failure cannot cause a signature calculation error, to the best of my knowledge.